# javascript horizontal scrolling date-time picker with current time always in center

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker

I need a time picker for synchronizing media recordings. 
See image below.
The current time should be indicated by cursor in the middle,
time can be changed by scrolling the timeline horizontally.

I was hoping to not need to reinvent the wheel and build it from scratch, but I can find no available time or range picker that behaves like this.

I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction with regards to either building one from scratch, or using an existing component.

[image: time picker]